# software update for logitech unifying receiver won't execute

Tags: updates, software-center, 17.04, logitech-unifying

I have a logitech K350  keyboard mouse combo. Checking Ubuntu Software shows one update, see screenshot, related to Bastille exploit.

I click install and nothing happens.

I remove unifying receiver to try wired peripherals to click install but then update vanishes.

What next?

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue, and no idea how to get this fixed. Were you able to make any progress on this?

Comment: Zero. Zilch. Nada.

Comment: Same here on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04.  Although the update does not vanish when I unplug the receiver. The behaviour does not change. Try adding labels/tags for your ubuntu version and flavour to improve the visibility of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue even after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10. What worked for me was to do `sudo fwupdmgr refresh` from terminal and then try to update Logitech Unified Receiver by `sudo fwupdmgr update` as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/384557). NB! It is enough to execute the first refresh command only once. But if you get a timeout for a second command (just as in original problem):

```
sudo fwupdmgr update
Downloading RQR12.07_B0029 for Unifying Receiver...
Updating RQR12.07_B0029 on Unifying Receiver...
Decompressing…         [-                                       ]
request timed out
```

then unplug and replug the receiver and try again. It might fail because  you tried to update firmware with old software before, and it might take some time until receiver starts responding again. For simplicity, you might execute the first command `sudo fwupdmgr refresh`, restart, see that your Logitech device works, and then execute second command `sudo fwupdmgr update`.

PS! The message from graphical update manager disappeared only after another restart.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it simply didn't work on my Ubuntu 17.04.

It seem to work now when I've upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10.